# Redmine install on CentOs

Tags: redmine

I would like to install the Redmine on my CentOs 5 following the instructions on this link: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_Redmine_on_CentOS_5

I've reached until the "Configure Apache to host the documents" step without errors. At this step there's another link to succeed.
At basic steps on the 5th step there is a need to edit the rails path, but on the proposed path I dont have rails.

Do you have any idea where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

man, solved?

If not, try that (sorry about formatting on copying from solution page to here...):

[**install redmine (project management tool) on centos 5.4 with postgres backend**](http://gkoenig.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/install-redmine-project-management-tool-on-centos-5-4-with-postgres-backend/)

> - prerequisites   * enable the epel yum repository   * installed postgresql database (I’m using the latest 8.4 provided from pgdg
>     repository)
> - install some packages
>
>   > ```
>   > yum install ruby ruby-devel ruby-libs ruby-irb ruby-rdoc ruby-postgres rubygems
>   > gem install rails
>   > ```
> - create user/db
>
>   > ```
>   > su postgres
>   > createuser -P redmine (no superuser, can create databases)
>   > psql -U redmine postgres
>   > postgres#>create database redmine;
>   > postgres#>\q
>   > ```
> - download latest stable redmine from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=1850
>
>   > ```
>   > cd /opt
>   > wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/67144/redmine-0.8.7.tar.gz
>   > tar -xvzf redmine-0.8.7.tar.gz
>   > ```
> - edit ruby database configuration
>
>   > ```
>   > cd redmine-0.8.7
>   > cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
>   > vi config/database.yml
>   > ```
> - modify the settings to your recently created database
>
>   > production:
>   >
>   > adapter: postgresql
>   >
>   > database: redmine
>   >
>   > host: localhost
>   >
>   > username: redmine
>   >
>   > password:
>   >
>   > encoding: utf8
> - create a session store (for storing session cookies)
>
>   > ```
>   > rake config/initializers/session_store.rb
>   > ```
> - create the database structure for your configured database in the “production” section
>
>   > ```
>   > RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
>   > ```
> - populate the tables with some initial data
>
>   > ```
>   > RAILS_ENV=production rake redmine:load_default_data
>   > ```
> - set some file permissions (assumption: you’ll run redmine as user redmine)
>
>   > ```
>   > cd /opt/redmine-0.8.7
>   > sudo chown -R redmine:redmine files log tmp public/plugin_assets
>   > sudo chmod -R 755 files log tmp public/plugin_assets
>   > ```
> - adjust your mailserver settings
>
>   > ```
>   > cp config/email.yml.example config/email.yml
>   > vi config/email.yml
>   > ```
> - ...insert your mailserver/credentials and method of sending emails
> - start the webserver as the user you “enabled” in the previous step
>
>   > ```
>   > ruby script/server webrick -e production
>   > ```
> - the builtin web-server will start.
> - Now you can point your browser to `http://localhost:3000` and you’ll see the welcome page, click “sign in” and type credentials
>     “admin”/”admin”.
> - now you are logged in.
> - As this admin user you can start creating users, projects, issues, ….